# Why do the email job notifications have multiple instances of the same job in the same email message?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, stack-overflow-jobs

This question is not the same as other questions about receiving multiple emails about the same job offer. This question is about email job notifications that contain more than one copy of the same job listing in a single email message. If there is only one job that meets my interest criteria, then the email notification about that single job should only list the job once.

Listing the same job twice in the same email message comes off looking "spammy" and presents a negative perception of Stack Overflow, which is something none of us would want.

Is there any way to re-write the automated email job notification system to only list a specific job once on each email notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 search alerts that are *almost* the same (one has 2 more technologies you don't want to work with), and we matched the same job to the two different alerts.

This has been fixed and from now on, even if a job matches 2 alerts, we will only send it on the first one, thanks for the report!

By the way, you can always [manage your job alerts here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/current)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and fix. I'll look into my alerts and fix them as well.